# What is the term for an idea that requires/creates its opposite?

Tags: antonyms, single-word-requests, concept

An example would be that the concept of 'light' necessitates an opposite: 'dark.' The idea of one entails the other. Is there a term for this?

Comment: A word opposite in meaning is called an **antonym**. I think there is a difference between a concept which can have an opposite, and words that have antonyms. Sometimes, a concept has a clear opposite, but there is just no single word to express that meaning, i.e. no antonym.

Comment: @FX_ I'm not talking about antonyms, but ideas that cannot exist without describing an opposite phenomenon. Maybe this is confusing, but it's like if you build a wall, immediately you are separating two things that would not have existed without creating the wall in the first place. If you introduce the concept of 'good,' you are concomitantly inventing 'bad.'

Comment: And if you invent "cheese" you are simultaneously inventing "non-cheese"? I think the word you're looking for is something like "concept" or "word". Some linguists would argue that words only have meaning because they divide the world up into different categories, each having a different word distinguishable from other words by not sounding like them, so whenever you create a concept N you automatically leave behind everything else as not-N.

Answer (score 6):

*Antithesis* is a counter-proposition, necessitating a proposition.

Answer (score 1):

I would either call it dialectical (or, under certain circumstances, controversial).

According to http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dialectical, "dialectic" is:

> The process especially associated with
>   Hegel of arriving at the truth by
>   stating a thesis, developing a
>   contradictory antithesis, and
>   combining and resolving them into a
>   coherent synthesis.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would go with *quality* as the good and the bad are a matter of quality.

One of the Tao texts i have places this under *Qualities* but another has it under *Self-Manifestation through Contraries*.

antithesis and dialectical don't really fit as what this is a property of human perception which need not be phrased in terms of logical propositions.

note well that what is called *the unity of opposites* is a fallacy because good can exist with evil but we can't recognize the good without knowing the evil and vise versa so i offer the qualification that it's the *perceptive opposites* that are unified.

Answer (score 0):

"Complement" is the best English word. It means "one of two mutually completing parts", per Merriam Webster.

Alternatively, you could use the adjective "dichotomous" which means "dividing into two parts" per Merriam-Webster.